# Is this formula correct and if yes why?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to find a formula that will calculate in how many ways can N same objects (so not a permuation) be placed in row in K boxes.

**Examples:**

$\ N=2 , K=8 => 7 $ ways $(1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, 5-6, 6-7, 7-8)$

$\ N=3 , K=8 => 6 $ ways $(1-2-3,2-3-4,3-4-5,4-5-6,5-6-7,6-7-8)$

Through examples like those above I have found that the formula that calculates what I want is $T=K-N+1 , N \le K$ where $T$ the result I want. Is this formula correct ? And if it is why ?

Comment: I don't understand your examples. What does your notation $(1-2,2-3,3-4,...)$ mean?

Comment: @kccu 1-2 for example means that the 2 objects are placed in the 1st and 2nd box. The remaining places are empty or can be filled with something else we don't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because the first of the $N$ objects can be placed either in the $1$st, $2$nd, ..., or $(K-N+1)$th box. The last case corresponds to the $N$th of the $N$ objects placed in the $K$th box.

Comment: Very nice explanation

Comment: just to make sure. If I want to count the ways where N same objects are not placed in row in K boxes then the formula is $T = C(K,N) - (K-N+1)$ ?

Comment: @NickDelta Sounds right, if you allow arrangements like $1-2-4$ where some objects but not all are adjacent.

Comment: Exactly my condition. Thanks once again.